# List the order of GridView Events in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, events, gridview

Like Page Life Cycle events, Can anyone list the order of the GridView Events?
This question has been asked in an interview. I am googling it but couldn't get the desired answer.

Comment: All events? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx It also depends, some events are only called in specific situations, for example `RowDataBound` after you've called `grid.DataBind()`, other always like `RowCreated`. It also depends on if it's the initial load or a postback. You should **not need to rely on that order**.

Comment: Order of all the events. Then please mention the default events that would always takes place in GridView.

Comment: [Control Execution Lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719775%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: thank you Tim Schmelter & Magnus.

Comment: I must say, that is quite a strange question to ask during an interview. I think most people would need to look this up.

Comment: Yes. This is a very strange question. Thatswhy not able to find the exact answer too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the order I get:

```
Init
Load
DataBinding
RowCreated
RowDataBound
RowCreated
RowDataBound
...
RowCreated
RowDataBound
DataBound
PreRender
Unload
```

I haven't listed the SelectedIndexChanging/SelectedIndexChanged, PageIndexChanging/PageIndexChanged, Sorting/Sorted and row editing and deleting events.

Comment: Don't forget RowCommand, RowEditing/RowEdited/RowCancelingEdit, RowDeleting/RowDeleted, RowUpdating/RowUpdated...